# Python Adding Methods at runtime

Tags: python, class, methods, class-method

I'm trying to dynamically add methods to classes at runtime, and am seeing some issues:

```
#Here we define a set of symbols within an exec statement and put them into the dictionary d
d = {}
exec "def get_%s(self): return self.%s" % (attr_name, attr) in d

#Now, we bind the get method stored in d['get_%s'] to our object (class)
func = d['get_%s' % (attr_name)].__get__(d['get_%s' % (attr_name)], class)
setattr(class_instance, func.__name__, func)
```

When I try to call the generated get method, I see the below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Textere_AdvancedExample.py", line 77, in <module>
    count = fact.get_counter()
  File "<string>", line 1, in get_counter
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_counter'
```

### Edit

Based on some of the exceptional responses given so far, I think I need to clarify why I'm doing things this way.

I'm trying to build an annotation like the below example:

```
@getters
@singleton
class A() {

    def __init__(self):
        self._a = "a"
        self._b = "b"
 }
```

Based on the names present in the class, the annotation will build getters for the private class variables at runtime and bind them to the singleton instance.

The strategy I've taken is to have an Application Context class with a set of dicts.  Then, the context is passed in to the annotation, which adds the instance & class into these dicts.

On startup, the Application Context is then responsible for reading the dictionaries and then building & binding get methods to the respective singleton object.

### Edit2

So this development started after some discussions with friends of mine who are Java developers regarding two libraries in particular: Spring & [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html)

I wanted to see if these particular pieces of functionality could be implemented in Python.  So the application context came about originally from trying to get a functionality similar to Spring's autowire annotation.  I got this working without issue.

Then, I got the generating the getters and setters and realized that I was going to have a fundamental difference in Python from the Java implementation: Lombok does this at compile time and Python is not compiled.  This meant that I had to dynamically generate methods based on what's being annotated and bind them to objects manually, all at runtime.  Thus, you see this sort of warping of the Java implementation.

For those interested, The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/AO-StreetArt/Textere)

Comment: Are you actually trying to add methods to **instances** at runtime? The 1. argument to `function.__get__()` should be the instance that a method is bound to (passed as the 1. argument, usually self) and you're passing the function itself. The exception points this out: "**'function' object** has no attribute ...".

Comment: Feels like this might be an XY problem. What are you actually trying to achieve by dynamically adding methods to class instances? Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: After reading your edit, I don't really understand what you want to achieve. Do not ask a new question about it because it would probably be too broad, but you should add more context, mainly explain how you want to use that. I'm used to Spring's ApplicationContext, and I'm sure it is not the way they are built...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Its funny that you mention that, Spring was one of the things that lead me to exploring this functionality in Python.  I've added some further clarifications, perhaps you can suggest a better way to replicate Spring & Lombok within Python

Comment: Python annotation on classes could mimic some of Lombok's features, notably automatic getters and setters... except that Python uses properties instead of getters and setters, but a class annotation could generate all the boiling plate code around a property (this could lead to a SO question IMHO). For Spring, you could look at [pinject](https://github.com/google/pinject) for an example of DI implementation in Python...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily dynamically add static methods or class methods:

```
class A:
    pass

@staticmethod
def foo0(x):
    return x * 2

a = A()
A.foo = foo0
a.foo(3)
```

return `6`

```
class A:
    val = 3

@classmethod
def foo0(cls, x):
    return x * cls.val

a = A()
A.foo = foo0
a.foo(2)
```

return `6`

You can also add specific methods to an instance of a class (almost the same way)

```
class A:
    pass

a = A()
a.foo = (lambda x: 2*x)
a.foo(3)
```

returns `6`

You can also add an instance method to a class, through the use of the `types` module (in fact, this generic way can be used to create also static and class methods, as well as instance only methods):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val


a = A(3)
A.foo = types.MethodType((lambda self, x: self.val * x), None, A)
a.foo(2)
```

returns `6`

But this is really [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch), that is a quick and dirty hack that should only be used when you need to pass slightly changed classes and you are not allowed to change the name. The nice and clean way to add functionalities to a class is *inheritance*

---

Just to make this answer better, the above is valid for Python 2.

For Python 3, only the first way to create class and static method can be used, because the `types` module has lost many types.

And you create an instance method as simply as:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val


a = A(3)
A.foo = (lambda self, x: self.val * x)
a.foo(2)
```

returns `6`. No need for special construct here

Comment: Please see my edit, I'm not so sure that I can use these direct approaches since I'm generating these methods based on a class being passed to an annotation.

Comment: Great answer. I wonder why setattr cannot be used (as tried in the question).

Answer (score 0):

```
exec("%s.__dict__['get_%s'] = lambda self: self.%s" % (class_name, attr_name, attr_name))
```